# Domain & Double Integrals in Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus

> Let $D$ be a set
>
> where $D=$ { $(x,y)∈\mathbb{R^2}:9≤x^2+y^2≤16,y≥0$ }
>
> a) Draw D and describe the set  using polar coordinates.
>
> b) Solve $\iint_D exp(x^2+y^2)dA$
>
> c) Solve $\iint_D x*exp(x^2+y^2)dA$
>
> d) Find the largest and smallest value thatthe function $x*exp(x^2+y^2)$ has on the domain $D$

a) I could rewrite it as $9≤r≤16,r*sin(θ)≥0$. By writing it into polar coordinates. As I understand it I could draw the domain, using polar coordinates, as a circle hitting the above conditions for r, r being the radios of the circle. But how does $r*sin(θ)$ play into this?

b+c) I believe this to be simple rewriting the double integral in terms of polar coordinates. But I am unable to as I don't know the values of $r$ and $θ$

d) Uncertain how to proceed here.

Comment: What does $r \sin(\theta)$ being positive implies on $\theta$ knowing $r$ has to be positive ?

Comment: I would not reccomend writing $\theta$ that way since it forces you into one order of integration.  Instead think about what values trace out half of a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $y \geq 0$ so it is the region in between the two half circles of radius $3$ and $4$ in the upper half of the plane. In polar coordinates this is described by the region $D= \{(r,\theta):3\leq r \leq 4, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi \}$. For parts $b$ and $c$ use the coordinate transformation $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$ with the area differential $dA=rdrd\theta$. For part $d$ rewrite the function in polar coordinates and consider all possible values in $D$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am not certain how you find that $0≤y=≤θ≤π$. I can understand that it is a domain between two half circles, using the polar coordinates, but only because I know that $0≤y$. Is it simple based on that knowledge you are able to rewrite it?

Comment: Draw a picture. The angle $\theta$ is measured counterclockwise from the $x$ axis. For $y \geq 0$ you only consider the area above the $x$ axis so the minimum angle is $\theta=0$ and the maximum angle is $\theta=\pi$.